# php, mysql, "Else after while statement

Tags: php, mysql, database, phpmyadmin, mysqli

How can I write a  condition such that if the row wasn't found to  then do something?

My code

```
$resultt = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM objednavky WHERE kdo = '$kdo' and kdy = '$the_rday'");
                        while ($roww = mysql_fetch_array($resultt)) {

                            echo "<form method='post' action=''>
                                  <label for='obb1'>Menu #1&emsp;</label>
                                  <input type='text' name='obb1' value='$roww[3]' size='4'><br>
                                  <label for='obb1'>Menu #2&emsp;</label>
                                  <input type='text' name='obb2' value='' size='4'><br>
                                  <label for='obb1'>Menu #3&emsp;</label>
                                  <input type='text' name='obb3' value='' size='4'><br>
                                  <input type='submit' value='objednat'></form>";


                        }
```

And I want to continue like this

```
   ...} else {
echo " no match ";
}
```

Thank you so much for help.

Comment: Since you're using the mysql_ extension you can use [mysql_num_rows()](http://php.net/mysql_num_rows)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case you can use `mysql_num_rows()`

```
$resultt = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM objednavky WHERE kdo = '$kdo' and kdy = '$the_rday'");


   if(mysql_num_rows($resultt)<1){
   echo "not found";
   }else{

     while(...)

       }
```

Answer (score 2):

this can be done by [mysql_num_rows()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php)

```
 if($resultt && mysql_num_rows($resultt)>1){


             while ($roww = mysql_fetch_array($resultt)) {

                        echo "<form method='post' action=''>
                              <label for='obb1'>Menu #1&emsp;</label>
                              <input type='text' name='obb1' value='$roww[3]' size='4'><br>
                              <label for='obb1'>Menu #2&emsp;</label>
                              <input type='text' name='obb2' value='' size='4'><br>
                              <label for='obb1'>Menu #3&emsp;</label>
                              <input type='text' name='obb3' value='' size='4'><br>
                              <input type='submit' value='objednat'></form>";


                    }}  else {
                         echo " no match ";
                       }
```

but the use of `mysql_*` function is deprecated so use `pdo` or `mysqli` instead